# Listview prints Object not string java

Tags: java, android, listview, object

I'm trying to display a listview with data out of openERP / odoo.
OpenERP returns an list of objects that I'm trying to use into a listview, but it prints out "Ljava.lang.object@number".

listOfValues return the list of objects, in my onPostExecute I want to connect it with the listview. But it doesn't work, anyone suggestion?

private class ListViewLoaderTask extends AsyncTask{

```
    @Override
    protected SimpleAdapter doInBackground(String... strJson) {
        connector=new OpenerpRpc(getBaseContext());
        connector.Config();
        current_page += 1;
        listOffValues = getListOffFieldValues(current_page, false, listOffValues);

        String[] from = { "project_id"};
        int[] to = { R.id.tv_address};
        SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getBaseContext(), listOffValues, R.layout.lv_gps_layout, from, to);
        return adapter;
    }
    /** Invoked by the Android on "doInBackground" is executed */
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(final SimpleAdapter adapter) {
        // Setting adapter for the listview
        mListView.setAdapter(adapter);

        for(int i=0;i<adapter.getCount();i++){

            HashMap<String, Object[]> hm = (HashMap<String, Object[]>) adapter.getItem(i);
            final HashMap<String, String> companyDetails = new HashMap<String, String>();
            Object po_ids = (Object[]) hm.get("project_id");
            Object[] ret=(Object[]) hm.get("project_id");
            Integer number =  ((Integer) hm.get("project_id")[0]);
            String projectId =  ((String) hm.get("project_id")[1]);
            companyDetails.put("project_id",projectId);

            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) {
                    String listName;
                    HashMap<String, String> hmDownload = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    String l = companyDetails.get("project_id");
                    Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, YardActivity.class);
                    myIntent.putExtra("id", Long.toString(id));
                    myIntent.putExtra("position", Integer.toString(position)); //Optional parameters
                    MainActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);
                }
            });

        }
        progress.dismiss();
        Log.d("/****","Data from odoo is finished");
    }
}
```

Here is the output when i debug:

http://i62.tinypic.com/24esx87.png

I updated my example where you can see that I can get the name of the project out of the list. But when I try to visulize that It print that java.lang string. Is your solution the only solution? When I hit on an item in my listview I get the projectId that I hit, so why it dont what to visiulize the string value?

Comment: projectID = (String) hm.get("project_id")[1];
The default implementation returns the full name of the type
and that's why it's Ljava.lang.object@number
** i'm not sure nut i believe

Comment: How to print the string value?

Comment: create your model instead of putting it in object
that returns the real id

Comment: Can you explain little bit more? Because i still have no idea

Comment: HashMap<String, Object[]> hm = (HashMap<String, Object[]>) adapter.getItem(i);

change to HashMap<String, MyModel[]> hm = (HashMap<String, MyModel[]>) adapter.getItem(i);

where my model is a class you create that describe your data,
hold on i'm gonna grab a sample

Comment: take a look at ObjectItem.java http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/09/android-listview-with-adapter-example.html

Comment: I updated my code, I updated my example where you can see that I can get the name of the project out of the list. But when I try to visulize that It print that java.lang string. Is your solution the only solution? When I hit on an item in my listview I get the projectId that I hit, so why it dont what to visiulize the string value?

Comment: could upload the a full sample code so i could run it and solve it for you?

Comment: I'm trying the sample code now what you gave me ;-) If that doesnt work I will let you know!

Comment: It works, but how do I get the values of an ArrayAdapter based on their position? If I clicked the 5th I get position Id is 5 but how do I get the information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
HashMap<String, Object[]> hm = (HashMap<String, Object[]>)adapter.getItem(i);
```

change to

```
HashMap<String, MyModel[]> hm = (HashMap<String, MyModel[]>) adapter.getItem(i);
```

where my model is a class you create that describe your data,

take a look at `ObjectItem.java`
http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/09/android-listview-with-adapter-example.html